# Table in a tooltip when hovering over the icon

Tags: c#, asp.net, tooltip, tabular

In an asp.net page more exactly in a datalist I have a column with icons, when hovering over the icon I need to get alot of inforamtion and I would like to format it as a table.

Something like that:

```
name: PersonName
date: 12/12/2012
modified: 13/12/2011
```

And so on, how is this possible to implement in asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AjaxToolKit's HoverMenu, static example is given below even you can make it dynamically.

```
<ajaxToolkit:HoverMenuExtender ID="hme2" runat="Server"
TargetControlID="Panel9"
PopupControlID="PopupMenu"
HoverCssClass="popupHover"
PopupPosition="Left"
OffsetX="0"
OffsetY="0"
PopDelay="50" />

<asp:Panel CssClass="popupMenu" ID="PopupMenu" 
    runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
        CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
    <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" 
        CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
</asp:Panel>
```

[Go here for HoverMenu Demo](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HoverMenu/HoverMenu.aspx)